# Using Access database for webpage, concurrent user issues

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have a simple access database that resides on a network drive.  All of the people that need to make any modifications to this database have access on their machine, but they would like to have a read-only website just displaying the data contained in it.  I set up a website and tried using the accessdatasource, and while I could connect, it had issues whenever a user had the database open in access.  I swapped to using a sqldatasource with a connection string set up according to www.connectionstrings.com, but I seem to be having either the same or similar issues, depending on how I set up the string/database.  Basically, the entire issue is, if the database is opened by any user, the webpage is prevented from opening the database.  Is it possible to open the database read only from the webpage?

It is an access 2000 database, but everyone is using copies of access 2007, and in all of these instances, the ASP.NET user has read/write access to the network directory containing the database, and read access to the database itself.

When I use the connection string:

```
ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\<source>\<database>.mdb;User Id=<USER>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Mode=Share Deny Write;"
```

Where  is not the default "admin" user, and  is configured to have open/run (not open/exclusive) permissions on the database, I get the error:

> Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.

As far as I can tell, there is no workgroup information file, but I am not really sure what I am doing there.

When  is the default "admin" user, I get the error:

> Could not use ''; file already in use.

If someone has the database currently open, otherwise, it works fine.

And finally, if I use the connection string:

```
ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\<source>\<database>.mdb;User Id=<USER>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Mode=Read;"
```

I get the error:

> Could not lock file.

I have been googling this for the past several days now and I feel like I've just been going around in circles.  Any insight at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the answer is but `Mode=Share Deny Write` (first connectionString) is definitely wrong. That [Prevents others from opening in write mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171763(v=SQL.90).aspx) which won't work if there's already a writable connection open

Comment: Have you ruled out [this issue](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760280.aspx) where the ASP.NET user doesn't have access to write to the LDB file on directory that the MDB is located?

Comment: Yes, the user has permissions to the folder, if I use the accessdatasource or sqldatasource with default user, it can connect and display the data, as long as nobody has the database open in access.

Comment: Just to clarify I mean `NETWORK SERVICE` (or what ever [Identity you've configured ASP.NET to run under](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc1xthy.aspx)) not the user in the connection string

Comment: Right.  I have that part set up correctly.  It seems like my troubles right now are centered on accessing the database itself, specifically trying to open it read only, regardless of whether an ldb is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

As it's Access 2000 format there will definately have to be a workgroup file (.mdw) even if that has no security set as such. I would try the connection string whereby you also specify the workgroup location e.g:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=system.mdw;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Furthermore, I wouldn't recommend setting the read/write properties in the connection string, instead I think you would be better to create an account in the workgroup file and only assign it read only priviledges.

Update:

This is the ODBC connection method:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;
```

Comment: Where will I find the workgroup file, if the database is hosted on a network share server? (I don't have access, so anything I need to do is through making requests of the other people in my department, so it can be a little tedious)

Comment: It depends, if they have not secured the database then you may be able to access it without specifying the workgroup file, else you will need to bother someone for it's filepath. All this aside, you could try connecting using the ODBC driver instead of the OLEDB driver, I've added it into my answer.